# Can't configure apache (httpd) on fedora 23

Tags: apache, httpd.conf, fedora-23

I installed httpd (apache), it does not work, in log file i got this errors ->

```
[Mon Jun 27 18:59:26.121033 2016] [proxy:error] [pid 3827] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php-fpm/www.sock (*) failed
[Mon Jun 27 18:59:26.121136 2016] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 3827] [client ::1:44760] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

Here is my configuration as like [this](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Fedora_23&p=httpd)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oddly installing httpd alone does not require he php package.
The bottom line for the fix is located in /etc/httpd/conf.d/php.conf, it will try to use php-fpm if mod_php is unavailable.

```
# Redirect to local php-fpm if mod_php is not available
<IfModule !mod_php5.c>
  <IfModule !mod_php7.c>
    # Enable http authorization headers
    SetEnvIfNoCase ^Authorization$ "(.+)" HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=$1

    <FilesMatch \.php$>
        SetHandler "proxy:unix:/run/php-fpm/www.sock|fcgi://localhost"
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

So to fix this issue either make mod_php available

```
dnf install php
```

Or install and configure php-fpm.